# SQL CASE WHEN For DIfferent Criteria

Tags: sql-server

I have a query where I am trying to pull the development ratings of employees from 2012 and 2013:

```
SELECT Employee_ID, Meeting_Year, Meeting_Readiness_Rating
FROM  dbo.v_sc17_TMS_Data_Career_Meeting_Rating
GROUP BY Employee_ID, Meeting_Year, Meeting_Readiness_Rating
```

I am trying to setup the case when so it pulls 2012 ratings into one column and 2013 into another. I would like it to look like

```
Employee ID       2012 Meeting Rating        2013 Meeting Rating
```

Even if they did take one in 2012 but not in 2013 I still need data for both,  I am having a hard time figuring this out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Employee_ID, 
    CASE Meeting_Year WHEN 2012 THEN Meeting_Readiness_Rating ELSE NULL END as [2012 Meeting Rating],
    CASE Meeting_Year WHEN 2013 THEN Meeting_Readiness_Rating ELSE NULL END as [2013 Meeting Rating]
FROM  dbo.v_sc17_TMS_Data_Career_Meeting_Rating
GROUP BY Employee_ID, Meeting_Year, Meeting_Readiness_Rating
```

Comment: This doesn't combine them, it separates them into the separate years. For example if they have a Rating for 2012 and 2013 it will list the Rating for 2012 and NULL for 2013 then have another record with the rating for 2013 and NULL for 2012

Comment: yep, sorry, didn't read it carefully :) best answer from baltov

Answer (score 1):

```
   SELECT Employee_ID, sum(r2012) as '2012 Meeting Rating', sum(r2013) as '2013 Meeting Rating' from 
    (SELECT Employee_ID, 
       CASE Meeting_Year WHEN 2012 THEN Meeting_Readiness_Rating ELSE 0 END as r2012,
        CASE Meeting_Year WHEN 2013 THEN Meeting_Readiness_Rating ELSE 0 END as r2013 FROM  dbo.v_sc17_TMS_Data_Career_Meeting_Rating ) GROUP BY Employee_ID
```

Comment: I get a conversion error when I run this, trying to convert one of the actual ratings from NVARCHAR to INT

Comment: If Meeting_Readiness_Rating is not a number, convert it to number in CASE's

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  yr_2012.Employee_ID     
        ,yr_2012.Meeting_Readiness_Rating AS [2012_Meeting_Rating]
        ,yr_2013.Meeting_Readiness_Rating AS [2013_Meeting_Rating]
FROM    dbo.v_sc17_TMS_Data_Career_Meeting_Rating as yr_2012
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT  mr.Meeting_Readiness_Rating
            FROM    dbo.v_sc17_TMS_Data_Career_Meeting_Rating as mr
            WHERE   mr.Meeting_Year = '2013' AND
                    yr_2012.Employee_ID = mr.Employee_ID
        ) yr_2013
WHERE   Meeting_Year = '2012' ;
```

Comment: I need 2012 and 2013 though, why are you just using meeting year = 2013

Comment: you get 2012 in the outer query and 2013 in the inner query